# sumar horas tipo time

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una variable que es 18:00:00 osea las 6:00:00 pm y quiero sumarle otras 19:30:00 horas para que la variable resultante sea la hora 1:30 pm pero del siguiente dia.
Para luego generar una condición con esa nueva variable resultante:
por ejemplo 
que tal hora sea mayor a la variable que contiene la 1:30pm.

```
$hora5=("18:00:00");
$horali=date($hora5);
$horalimite2=date('H:i:s', strtotime($horali.' +19 hours'.' +30 minutes'));
echo $horalimite2;

 if($hentrega>$horalimite2)
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu error? que problma tienes?

Comment: quiero sumar a las 18:00:00 horas pm otras 19:30:00 par que me den como resultado las 1:30:00 pm  del siguiente día

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar esto

```php
<?
$F=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$SF=strtotime($F);

echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s",mktime(
  date("h",$SF)+19,
  date("i",$SF)+30,
  date("s",$SF),
  date("m",$SF),
  date("d",$SF),
  date("Y",$SF)
));
?>
```

`mktime` lo uso para descomponer la fecha

Sumo al bloque de horas 19

Sumo al bloque de minutos 30

Puedes usar solo la hora mira este ejemplo

```
$F=date("18:00:00");
$SF=strtotime($F);
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$SF);
```

Toma la fecha actual y agrega la hora que especifiques en formato 24 horas

Si requieres el formato en 12 hrs puedes usar `date("Y-m-d H:i:s a",$SF);`

Saludos :)

Comment: si en esta primera variable $F=date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); la pongo asi $F=date("18:00:00");  si me toma ese valor ? por que el otro es para que tome los valores del reloj y no quiero eso

Comment: ok , muchas gracias ya tomo la hora en 01:30:00 , ya contaría como si fuera la 1.30 pm del siguiente día ?

Comment: si ya lo cheque muchas gracias , pero mi duda es si al sumar a la hora 18:00:00pm digamos del dia 1 le sumo las 19:30:00, el resultado de una 1:30:00 pm corresponderia al dia 2 con el simple hecho de recorrer horas o tendria que aumentar +1 el campo del dia

Comment: ok ok y para uamntar en dias tengo esto .                     $f=date($fefac);                                                     
  $fechalimite=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f.' +1 days'));
    echo $fechalimite;

Comment: aa muy bien excelente , muchas gracias por resolver mis dudas . -Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El método `DateTime::add()` nos permite sumar o añadir una cantidad de tiempo (años; meses; dias; horas; minutos; segundos) a una fecha hora. También nos permite comparar fechas directamente.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$fecha = new DateTime('2018-09-07 18:00:00');
$fecha2 = clone $fecha;

$intervalo = new DateInterval('PT19H30M'); // intervalo de tiempo 19 horas y 30 min

echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a');

$fecha->add($intervalo); // añadimos, sumamos el intervalo de tiempo
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d h:i:s a');

// comparación 
if ($fecha >= $fecha2){
    echo 'fecha es mayor o igual a fecha2';
} else { 
    echo  'fecha es menor que fecha2';
}
```

Resultado

```
2018-09-07 06:00:00 pm
2018-09-08 01:30:00 pm
fecha es mayor o igual a fecha2
```

Documentación: http://www.php.net/manual/es/book.datetime.php

Comment: OK OK muchas gracias asi ya me queda mas claro